# Python Telegram bot delete MessageHandler after it is used

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have two `MessageHandlers` in two separate functions that takes in the same `Regex` Filters e.g. `\d+.*\d+`.

However I would like them to point to different functions. As of now when I call the first function, adding the first MessageHandler, the second `MessageHandler` would not get triggered at all.

I have tried using `dispatcher.remove_handler(handler_name)` but it still points to the first `MessageHandler`.

```
def func1(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  do something
  MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'\d+\.*\d*\s\d+\.*\d*\s\d+\.*\d*'), first_function)

def func2(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  do something
  MessageHandler(Filters.regex(r'\d+\.*\d*\s\d+\.*\d*\s\d+\.*\d*'), second_function)
```

Only the first `MessageHandler` will get triggered anytime I enter 123 123 123.

Comment: why you need that ?

Comment: I want each message handler to point to different functions. The first function would be to enter new values, the second function would be to edit the values in specific rows. So I need both the inputs to be the same

Comment: Why do not you call the second function in the first function?

Comment: The first function is used to add new values. If a user uses the /edit command, the user can input new values and edit. If I were to call the second function in the first function, then the user would have to edit the values after entering it.

Comment: For reference: This question has been asked in similar form at https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/2971

Comment: Are you familiar with conversation handler?

Comment: I just started coding using the telegram python bot api few days ago. I used conversation handler once. From my understanding there's states where the flow of the conversation is kind of sequential being A should happen then B and so on. What I am looking for is A can happen multiple times before B takes place. So I don't think I should use conversation handler in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. What I did was remove my second `MessageHandler` declaration. And instead I updated the handler's callback attribute to the other function e.g. `bot.handler.callback = second_function`